# An error occurs during the implementation of the linked list tree

Tags: c, arraylist, data-structures, tree

```
enter code here

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct _node {
   int data;
   struct _node* rightChild;
   struct _node* leftChild;
}Node;


Node* create(int data) { // create node function
   Node* node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
   node->rightChild = NULL;
   node->leftChild = NULL; 
   node->data = data;
   return node;
}

void Inorder(Node* ptr) { // travel
   if (ptr) 
   {
       printf("%c ", ptr->data);
       Inorder(ptr->leftChild);
       Inorder(ptr->rightChild); 
   }
 }
int main(void)
{
   Node* node[300];
   for (int i = 1; i < 300; i++) {
       if (i == 1) {
           node[i] = create(i);
       }
       else {
           if (i % 2 == 0) {
               node[i / 2]->leftChild = create(i);
           }
           else {
               node[i / 2]->rightChild = create(i);
           }
       }
   }
    Inorder(node[10]);
}
```

I would like to implement a binary tree using a Node* array, rather than taking variables input one by one. But I keep getting errors in that area. Thanks for the advice.Which part do I need to modify to make that part implemented through a for statement? As far as I understand, both the left and right parts of the node array have passed values, so why am I getting an error?

Comment: *But I keep getting errors in that area.* That might these errors be? Compilarion errors? Runtime errors? Wrong output? Please provide exact error message from compiler and/or precise description of the errors

Comment: If you haven't done it yet, then please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Please [edit] your question to improve it with a detailed description of the errors you get (for example a complete copy-paste (as text!) of your build-log if you get build errors).

Comment: `Node* node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(node));` -->> `Node* node = malloc(sizeof *node);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only `node[i]` you assign to is `node[1]`. All other nodes are linked via the the `leftChild` or `rightChild` fields.

You could fix this by doing, for example:

```
node[i] = create(i);
node[i / 2]->leftChild = node[i];
```

but I this is a bit roundabout, because you now have the same data – the handle to a node — in two different places.

My guess is that what you really want is a plain array of node structures, which are then linked via pointers into the array:

```
Node node[300] = {{0}};

node[1].data = 1;

for (int i = 2; i < 300; i++) {
    node[i].data = i;        

    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        node[i / 2].leftChild = &node[i];
    } else {
        node[i / 2].rightChild = &node[i];
    }
}
```

This creates a flat array of nodes, where the nodes are linked like a binary tree. For example, `node[1].leftChild` is a pointer to `node[2]`. You can use regular tree functions by passing `&node[1]` as head:

```
Inorder(&node[1]);
```

(What you call `Inorder` is really a pre-order traversal.)

The advantage is that you don't need to `create` and allocate anything. When `main` ends, the whole tree is gone without needing to `free`. (It also gets rid of a bug in `create`, where you allocate space for a pointer only, not for a node; it should be `node = malloc(sizeof(*node));`.)

Perhaps that's not what you want, but the bug in your code comes from accessing `node[2]` when it hasn't been set.